# helm-grep-do-git-grep: possible to show results in minibuffer?

Tags: search, helm-grep

When I use `helm-grep-do-git-grep` results are shown in the current window or a different one, but it takes the whole window. It there an option to show results in the minibuffer, below the current window where one is searching? Thanks!

Comment: Results are displayed below the current window by default, so you may want to check your configuration first.

Comment: Where do I check this? What part of the configuration?

Comment: Your helm configuration. Try running `helm-grep-do-git-grep` from `emacs-helm.sh`. If results are shown below, then something in your .emacs/init.el file is causing the undesired behaviour.

Comment: What does "running from "emacs-helm.sh" mean?

Comment: It means using Helm without your configuration. See [here](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki#quick-try-with-emacs-helmsh) for more information.

Comment: I see, thanks! However, the result panel shows in the right, as in my personal config. Of course, I work usually with C-x 3 (two vertical windows). And the results show on the right. If I have only one window, it shows in the minibuffer. How to make it show in minibuffer always?

Comment: Try changing `helm-always-two-windows` or `helm-split-window-inside-p`.